# Adding Products to Shopping Cart

Tags: shopping-cart, mini-cart, cart-items

I'm using v1.9. When a customer adds products to cart, it only shows the last 3 (looking to the customer like the other products haven't been added) please could you advise?

see [example](http://www.andrewsgreengrocers.co.uk)

Answer (score 0):

You Can change the number of Items to displayed in

> system->configurations->sales->checkout->shopping cart
>   sidebar->Maximum number of product to display

But your cart count is also not updating you need to check for that , but show more than three items in cart you can use above settings

Answer (score 0):

By default magento show latest 3 item. You can change the number of item to be displayed using

*"system->configurations->sales->checkout->shopping cart sidebar->Maximum number of product to display"*
[image]